# Laravel Erro count() laravel/datatables 5.2 PHP -v 7.2

Tags: laravel

O seguinte erro com datatables:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Função:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

No PHP 7.2 o count de null passou a emitir uma Exception, nas versões anteriores ele retornava 0, o código vai ter que ser refatorado para efetuar esse tratamento. Provavelmente o seu erro está acontecendo devido a posição columns está vindo NULL.

Um abraço!

Comment: Provavelmente terá que fazer um upgrade da versão do laravel, já que não tem mais atualizações para a 5.2 há um tempo.

Comment: Estou ciente disso JuniorNunes, porém o projeto já esta em implantação e o tempo de upgrade seria complicado

Comment: @iMuriloCruz então rode com a versão do PHP especificada na [documentação](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2): `PHP version between 5.5.9 - 7.1.*`